# Classes.dex file size increased after ionic framework updated

Tags: java, android, google-analytics, ionic-framework

I have created an app using Ionic framework and for the first time the apk file size was 2.5mb and to add the google analytics plugin I have update the ionic framework and after that the file size increased to 3.7mb I'm sure that nothing is changed or added other than GA plugin. I have extracted the apk and identified that the classes.dex file size is 3.4mb before it was 900kb.

Does anyone have any clue on why the file size is increased?

[image: Extracted Apk folder]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is solved by downgrading the Cordova from 5.x.x to 4.2.0. Also, we have identified and installed the plugins which supports Cordova 4.2.0.

Then removed the sqlite library and unnecessary ionic js, css and fonts from the lib folder.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I assume that adding the GA plugin adds the GA libraries to your application (they're needed to use GA). The GA libraries are notoriously huge, as you've just discovered, therefor the increase in the size of your app.

If the size of your apk concerns you, take a look at http://blog.ionic.io/minifying-your-source-code for ways to make it as small as possible,

Comment: I've tried uninstalling the GA plugin but the file size remains the same and I've already used JShint and Uglify. Now I've identified changes in platforms\android folder after the Ionic update but don't have any clue on what to do.